# how to make angular-gridster widget data content responsive?

Tags: angularjs, gridster, angular-grid

i'm using angular-gridster for designing dynamic user dashboard. how can we make gridster widget data content responsive while resizing widget callback, can any one suggest me how to make it responsive.

```
 <div id="gridster" >
                <div gridster="gridsterOpts">
                    <ul>
                        <li gridster-item="widget" ng-repeat="widget in DashboardControls">
                            <div class="box">
                                <div class="box-header">
                                    <h3 style="width: 100%;word-break: break-all; table-layout: fixed;">{{widget.ControlobjectName}}</h3>
                                    <div class="box-header-btns pull-right">
                                        <a title="settings" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#widgetSettingModal" ng-click="openSettings(widget)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i></a>
                                        <a title="Remove widget" ng-click="remove(widget)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="box-content">
                                    <div>                                       
                                         <img class="img-responsive"  ng-src="{{widget.ThumbnailPath}}" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: :- Did you find the answer for this question ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a custom directive that is embedded into the widgets (or multiple custom directives). This custom directive can contain logic that responds to the data and changes the content of the widgets.